# Notifications disabled for my Android app in android setting after updating the code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-notifications

I updated my android App(Java) code to `minSdkVersion 22` and `targetSdkVersion 31` and `compileSdkVersion 31` and `buildToolsVersion 31.0.0` and right now I have a problem.

When I test my App after updating the code, notifications are not showed, so I checked android setting and I saw that Notificatios are disabled for my App, when I enabled it, Notifications started showing automattically. Im testing on Android 12 phone.

What happened and what I have to do? My app shows an ongoing permanent notification to show date and time. It worked nice and after updating code, it's not.

My notification service called and running normally, just Notifications disabled in android setting.

Comment: Have you added work manager in your notification class in onMessageReceived function?

Comment: @Sandesh: No I didn't. the code is the same, just not working on android 12. It's not about background updating the notification, Notification does not start to show even for the first time when the App is open. Why  notification disabled for my App already? What happened?

Comment: Compare with the official documents once-https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging/app/src/main